# Error in Calculator: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, function, calculator, typeerror

I have learning Python to do my final project. I have begun doing a simple calculator. The code is almost finished but I have an error.

Program give me result fine, but when I try to do another operation program gives me this issue:

> **TypeError:** 'float' object is not callable

Program shows menu to choose the operator. After that, asks user the value of number1 and number2 and checks if the value is a number by the function *def numero1()* and *def numero2()*

Please could you help me to solve it?

The program code is the following:

```
import os #Importamos librerias que se usan en el programa
import sys
import time

def menu(): #Funcion para crear el menu
    os.system('cls') 
    print ("********** Menu de la calculadora **********")
    print ("\t1 - Sumar")
    print ("\t2 - Restar")
    print ("\t3 - Multiplicar")
    print ("\t4 - Dividir")
    print ("\t9 - Salir") 

def numero1(): #Funcion para introduir un numero como primer valor 
     while True:
        try:
            numero1 = float(input("Inserta el primer valor: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Introduce un número")
        else:
            return numero1

def numero2(): #Funcion para introducir un numero como segundo valor 
    while True:
        try:
            numero2 = float(input("Inserta el segundo valor: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Introduce un número")
        else:
            return numero2

#Definimos 2 variables que vamos a usar
operador = 0
i = 1

#Mientas que la variable i sea mayor que cero se ejecuta el bucle (SIEMPRE)
while i > 0 :
    # Mostramos el menu
    menu()
    #Preguntamos que operacion quiere realizar
    operador = input("¿Que operación quieres realizar?: ")
    while operador != "1" and operador != "2" and operador != "3" and operador != "4" and operador != "9":
        os.system('cls')
        menu()
        print("Introduce un operador correcto")
        operador = input("¿Que operación quieres realizar?: ")

    if operador == "9": #Si es 9 cerramos el programa
        os.system('cls')
        print("SALIENDO.")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('cls')
        print("SALIENDO..")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('cls') 
        print("SALIENDO...")
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()


    #Realizamos una operacion u otra
    if operador == "1":
        numero1 = numero1()
        numero2 = numero2()
        resultado = numero1 + numero2        
    elif operador == "2":
        numero1 = numero1()
        numero2 = numero2()
        resultado = numero1 - numero2      
    elif operador == "3":
        numero1 = numero1()
        numero2 = numero2()
        resultado = numero1 * numero2
    elif operador == "4":
        numero1 = numero1()
        numero2 = numero2()
        resultado = numero1 / numero2    

    #Mostramos el resultado en pantalla y preguntamos si realizamos otra operación    
    print("El resultado es: ",resultado)
    salir =(input("Pulsa cualquier tecla para realizar otra operación o 9 para salir..."))
    if salir == "9":
        os.system('cls')
        print("SALIENDO.")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('cls')
        print("SALIENDO..")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('cls') 
        print("SALIENDO...")
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: full traceback please, and try printing `type(float)`, you may have shadowed the type by something else.

Comment: When you're checking if `operador` equals `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, or `"4"`, you've unnecessarily repeated the same lines of code in each case. Simply place them above the first `if` statement in that section to improve the clarity of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use variable names that are identical to function names. One will overwrite the other. If you do `numero1 = numero1()`, then `numero1` in that scope will permanently become a floating point number, and the function object will no longer be accessible.

Change your variables names so that none of them are `numero1` or `numero2`.

Comment: Oh thank you!! It's works :D I didn´t knew that the name of variables and the name of functions have to be different. I have changed the name of functions numero1 now is n1 and numero2 now is n2. But I still dont know why the functions are inaccesible after one operation...